# Can i convert if I'm pregnant?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, pregnancy-birth

I was late 3 days and my biyfrend was concerned that his familly wouldnt accept the baby because i haven't started the conversion process, i dont even know how to start,Is it possible to have a speedy conversion so my baby is Jewish at birth?

Comment: Short answer is no. Long answer is there's no such thing as a speedy conversion process, and more than that I was told that a Jewish Court won't convert a pregnant woman due to the complications involved. If your boyfriend's family will accept a convert then they'll accept a child that's a convert.

Comment: This site is not the right place for personal questions, you and your boyfriend should speak with his rabbi. Conversion is not an easy process and requires serious motivation, the rabbi will be able to share more details. Good luck

Comment: Also, once the mother is converted, even if it takes a couple of years, converting a baby or a little kid is really easy.